# Django- 'QuerySet' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I hope someone can give me a hand with this. I have a form with a table inside. In the table a have checkboxes for each row so the user can select which documents export to an excel file. This is my HTML:

```
<tbody>
    {% for factura in facturas %}
    <tr>
       <td><i class="fa fa-file"> <a href="{% url 'ver_Factura' factura.pk %}">Ver</a></i>
           <div class="checkbox">
               <label>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="factura" value="{{ factura.pk }}">
               </label>
           </div>
       </td>
       <td>{{ factura.nombre_cliente }}</td>
       <td>{{factura.numero_De_Factura }}</td>
       <td>{{factura.fecha_factura }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

 </tbody>
```

i have this code in my views.py for this Export function:

```
def descarga(request):
    selected_values = request.POST.getlist('factura')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Factura.objects.filter(id__in=selected_values)
        **print form**
        if form:
            book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf8')
            sheet = book.add_sheet('report')
            sheet.col(0).width = int(13*380)
            sheet.col(1).width = int(13*380)
            sheet.col(2).width = int(13*380)
            sheet.col(3).width = int(13*380)
            sheet.col(4).width = int(13*380)
            sheet.col(5).width = int(13*380)
            sheet.col(6).width = int(13*380)
            sheet.col(7).width = int(13*380)

       (...Style of the sheet here...)

       (...Headers of the sheet here)



            **for facturas in form:
                 data = {
                     "Cliente": form.nombre_cliente,
                     "Fecha de Factura":form.fecha_factura,
                     "Tipo de Factura": form.tipo_Factura,
                     "Numero de Factura": form.numero_De_Factura,
                     "Descripcion": form.descripcion,
                     "Subtotal": form.importe_sin_iva,
                     "IVA": form.iva,
                     "Precio": form.importe_Total,
                 }**



            for column, key in enumerate(header, start=1):
                sheet.write(1, column, str(data[key]), body_style)


            response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.xls'
            response = render_to_response("facturas.html",context_instance=RequestContext(request), mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
            book.save(response)
            return response
```

As you can see i´m printing the "form" object to see what it contains on the console and (If i choose only 2 files in the table) i get this in the console:

```
[<Factura: Andreani Logistica S.A - 2231231243>, <Factura: Pechugs LAru - 23423421>]
```

The problem is that in this part:

```
**for facturas in form:
             data = {
                 "Cliente": form.nombre_cliente,
                 "Fecha de Factura":form.fecha_factura,
                 "Tipo de Factura": form.tipo_Factura,
                 "Numero de Factura": form.numero_De_Factura,
                 "Descripcion": form.descripcion,
                 "Subtotal": form.importe_sin_iva,
                 "IVA": form.iva,
                 "Precio": form.importe_Total,
             }**
```

im getting the error :

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'nombre_cliente'
```

but as you can see there is an object **Factura** in the querySet that has that value.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to fix this? or just point me in the right direction.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please don't call things "form" when they are not forms. That is a queryset of Factura objects, not a form.

Comment: maybe you need `facturas.nombre_cliente`? form is a queryset, list of objects, it doesn't have these attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating through facturas in form. To get to particular `nombre_cliente` attribute from one factura you need to use `facturas.nombre_cliente` not `form.nombre_cliente`.